# Console outputs a ton of gibberish after entering string with std::cin into while loop

Tags: c++, while-loop, console, std

I'm getting an odd output of gibberish to the console after getting into a while loop to get confirmation from the player that the right name is entered.

The loop works just fine for the difficulty level confirmation check, but goes crazy for the play name confirmation.

You can see some of the debug attempts I've made in the "SetPlayerName" function and everything is fine.

Compiles fine no errors, I'm pretty lost. I've tried .clear and .ignore even right after the string input and everything else I can think of to pinpoint where the issue is.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void PrintGameIntro ()
{
    std::cout << "\nGame Intro Text\n";
} 

// Sets the level constraints for the game as well as getting the desired level and makes sure it's within the constraints so it can be confirmed and SET in SetGameDifficulty
int SelectGameDifficulty ()
{
    int GameDifficulty = 0;
    // Magic numbers for level constraints
    const int MaxLevel = 10;
    const int MinLevel = 1;

    // Get desired level and check that it is within the level constraints
    std::cout << "\nSelect game difficulty 1-10:\n";
    std::cin >> GameDifficulty;
    while (GameDifficulty > MaxLevel || GameDifficulty < MinLevel)
    {
        std::cout << "Please select a level from 1 to 10 or press CTRL-C to exit.\n";
        std::cin >> GameDifficulty;
    }
    return GameDifficulty;
}

// SETS the level difficulty after being SELECTED in SelectLevelDifficulty
int SetGameDifficulty ()
{
    bool bCorrectlevel = false;
    std::string CorrectLevelYesNo = "N";
    while (bCorrectlevel != true)
    {
        const int GameDifficulty = SelectGameDifficulty();
        std::cout << "\nYou selected a game difficulty level of " << GameDifficulty << " is this correct? \n Enter \'(Y)es\' or \'(N)o\'";
        std::cin >> CorrectLevelYesNo;
        if (CorrectLevelYesNo == "Yes" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "Y" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "yes" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "y")
        {
            bCorrectlevel = true;
            return GameDifficulty;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please select a difficulty and confirm it.";
        }
    }
}

std::string SetPlayerName()
{
    std::cout << "\nWhat is your name, agent?\n";
    std::string PlayerName;
    std::cin >> PlayerName;
    // BEGIN DEBUG STUFF
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    std::cout << "Not gibberish?";
    // END DEBUG STUFF
    bool bCorrectName = false;
    std::string CorrectNameYesNo = "N";
    int NameLoopCount = 1;
    
    // BEGIN DEBUG STUFF
    int TestInt = 15;
    std::cin >> TestInt;
    std::cout << TestInt << PlayerName;
    std::cout << "\nOk, " << PlayerName << ", then. Did I get that right?\n Enter \'(Y)es\' or \'(N)o\'\n";
    std::cin >> TestInt;
    // END DEBUG STUFF
    
    while (bCorrectName = false)
    {
        if(NameLoopCount > 1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nOhh, my mistake. I must be getting deaf in my old age. What was it then?\n";
            std::cin >> PlayerName;
        }
        std::cout << "\nOk, " << PlayerName << ", then. Did I get that right?\n Enter \'(Y)es\' or \'(N)o\'\n";
        std::cin >> CorrectNameYesNo;
        if (CorrectNameYesNo == "Yes" || CorrectNameYesNo == "Y" || CorrectNameYesNo == "yes" || CorrectNameYesNo == "y")
        {
            std::cout << "Alright then, " << PlayerName << ". Let's get started.";
            return PlayerName;
        }
        NameLoopCount ++;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    PrintGameIntro();        
    const int GameDifficulty = SetGameDifficulty();
    std::cin.clear();
    std::cin.ignore();
    const std::string PlayerName = SetPlayerName(); 
    std::cout << "game set to level " << GameDifficulty << " and player name is " << PlayerName <<".";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: in line 72, you have '=' inside while condition, is this on purpose, or did you mean '=='?

Comment: SOB, definitely not, that fixed the gibberish!

I feel dumb

thank you!

Comment: hmmm, but I would suggest using "std::endl" with std::court instead of '\n' since it also flushes output, and be careful with std::cin, since it only reads one word (if user enters multiple words, it could break your sequence of multiple std::cin), think about using getline instead of std::cin for this usecase

Comment: Yeah that's what I came across looking at other stuff. I swapped it out at one point and it wasn't making any difference (you know, because bad while loop condition) so I just went back to cin.

Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Turns out = and == are not the same thing. Thanks for the support @stribor14.

Now I know the compiler is totally ok with a "bad" (or rather, i think incomplete) while condition and it will cause

bum bum bummmmmm

a stack overflow hahaha

removed the debug steps i put in and it works as intended

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>

void PrintGameIntro ()
{
    std::cout << "\nGame Intro Text\n";
} 

// Sets the level constraints for the game as well as getting the desired level and makes sure it's within the constraints so it can be confirmed and SET in SetGameDifficulty
int SelectGameDifficulty ()
{
    int GameDifficulty = 0;
    // Magic numbers for level constraints
    const int MaxLevel = 10;
    const int MinLevel = 1;

    // Get desired level and check that it is within the level constraints
    std::cout << "\nSelect game difficulty 1-10:\n";
    std::cin >> GameDifficulty;
    while (GameDifficulty > MaxLevel || GameDifficulty < MinLevel)
    {
        std::cout << "Please select a level from 1 to 10 or press CTRL-C to exit.\n";
        std::cin >> GameDifficulty;
    }
    return GameDifficulty;
}

// SETS the level difficulty after being SELECTED in SelectLevelDifficulty
int SetGameDifficulty ()
{
    bool bCorrectlevel = false;
    std::string CorrectLevelYesNo = "N";
    while (bCorrectlevel != true)
    {
        const int GameDifficulty = SelectGameDifficulty();
        std::cout << "\nYou selected a game difficulty level of " << GameDifficulty << " is this correct? \n Enter \'(Y)es\' or \'(N)o\'";
        std::cin >> CorrectLevelYesNo;
        if (CorrectLevelYesNo == "Yes" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "Y" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "yes" || CorrectLevelYesNo == "y")
        {
            bCorrectlevel = true;
            return GameDifficulty;
        }
        else
        {
            std::cout << "Please select a difficulty and confirm it.";
        }
    }
}

std::string SetPlayerName()
{
    std::cout << "\nWhat is your name, agent?\n";
    std::string PlayerName;
    std::cin >> PlayerName;
    bool bCorrectName = false;
    std::string CorrectNameYesNo = "N";
    int NameLoopCount = 1;
    
    
    while (bCorrectName == false)
    {
        if(NameLoopCount > 1)
        {
            std::cout << "\nOhh, my mistake. I must be getting deaf in my old age. What was it then?\n";
            std::cin >> PlayerName;
        }
        std::cout << "\nOk, " << PlayerName << ", then. Did I get that right?\n Enter \'(Y)es\' or \'(N)o\'\n";
        std::cin >> CorrectNameYesNo;
        if (CorrectNameYesNo == "Yes" || CorrectNameYesNo == "Y" || CorrectNameYesNo == "yes" || CorrectNameYesNo == "y")
        {
            std::cout << "Alright then, " << PlayerName << ". Let's get started.";
            return PlayerName;
        }
        NameLoopCount ++;
    }
}

int main ()
{
    PrintGameIntro();        
    const int GameDifficulty = SetGameDifficulty();
    const std::string PlayerName = SetPlayerName(); 
    std::cout << "game set to level " << GameDifficulty << " and player name is " << PlayerName <<".";
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Are you sure this fixed it? When I copy paste your code and fix this, it still prints out the same lines over and over without stopping itself

Comment: there is a warning for this, maybe you have to enable it (and read it ;), its not a "bad" while conidtion btw, its just not the condition you want

Comment: once I removed the debug stuff it worked great

the .clear and .ignore were somehow shoving it back into the level select loop? not sure how or why and i know the understanding of that is WAY beyond me at my current coding level, but removing the debug stuff fixed it all

and idclev, yeah i thought about that after i wrote it, it's not "bad" in terms of syntax or whatever but it doesn't really "finish" the condition statement which sent it into stupidity